# Call Ruby blocks from C++ with Rice

Tags: c++, ruby

I am writing a Ruby interface for a C++ library I am writing right now. The C++ library provides several datastructures which are based upon a comparision function, for example a FibonacciHeap. Using the ruby comparision function works fine, i.e. the following Ruby code works:

```
f = FibonacciHeap.new
f.push(24)
f.push(2)
f.push(89)
raise unless f.top == 2
```

But I would like to make it possible for the user to provide his own comparision function, e.g. like this:

```
f = FibonacciHeap.new { |a, b| a.length <=> b.length }
f.push("asdf")
f.push("a")
f.push("adsfdsafdsaf")
raise unless f.top == "a"
```

But even using Google, I didn't find out how to use blocks in Rice. The only thing I found is how to define the ruby each method from C++ iterators, which of course takes a block. I guess as soon as I have stored the proc object, it is easy, I just call the ruby method "call" on it with the appropriate arguments, but how can I check if the constructor is given a block and if so, store the block into a proc object?

It would be even nicer, if I could check for the number of arguments the block takes, but I don't know if this is even possible, but then the user could in simple cases provide something like

```
f = FibonacciHeap.new { |a| a.length }
```

if he doesn't need the full flexibility of providing a `a <=> b` function.

Comment: Lol, why do I get the tumbleweed badge for this? It is not that stupid a question and I have researched before asking....

Comment: Any luck with this? I've come across a similar issue. Thanks! Edit: It looks as though Swig suports code blocks: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn34_2

Comment: I didn't find out anything new... One possibility would be to create a wrapper method in Ruby which calls the C++ method with a proc object that is created from the block. Then the C++ code cann just send "call" to the proc object. But it is terrible, you have to write a wrapper, you have to do type checking in C++ yourself etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C code, you can call:

```
rb_yield(value);
```

In Rice code, you can use:

```
Rice::protect(rb_yield, value);
```

(Rice::protect ensures normal C++ exception behavior).

This is how Rice::Module::define_iterator yield to ruby code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am working on something else now, so I won't try it out immediately, but thanks for the hint.